# Need help understanding why unit test for method is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I'm trying hard to cover all of my model's methods, associations and validation in my unit tests and so far it's going great. I've subscribed to TreeHouse and watched [Ruby Foundations - Testing](http://teamtreehouse.com/library/programming/ruby-foundations/testing) religiously.

I stumbled last night on this error while testing a method for my Provider.rb model:

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :description, :name
  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :description, :presence => true
  validates :name, :length => { :minimum => 6, :maximum => 100 }
  validates :description, :length => { :minimum => 6, :maximum => 100 }
  has_many :courses
  resourcify

  def unique_locations
    Location.joins(sessions: :course).where(courses: { provider_id: self.id }).uniq.pluck('locations.name')
  end

end
```

My unit test for the unique_locations method is the following:

```
  test 'should return a list of unique locations' do
    provider = FactoryGirl.build(:provider)
    assert_equal provider.unique_locations, ["location_1", "location_2"]
  end
```

I get the following error after running my tests:

```
<[]> expected but was
<["location_1", "location_2"]>.
```

My factories are quite simple:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :course do
    name 'Snowboard 101'
    description 'Snowboard course'
    association :provider, factory: :provider
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :provider do
    name 'The School of Hard Knocks'
    description 'School description'
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :session_snowboard, class: Session do
    name 'Winter Session'
    description 'Snowboarding 101'
    price 200
    class_size 4
    association :course, factory: :course
    association :location, factory: :location_1
  end

  factory :session_ski, class: Session do
    name 'skiing 101'
    description 'Start in november'
    price 100
    class_size 4
    association :course, factory: :course
    association :location, factory: :location_2
  end

end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :location_1 do
    name 'location_1'
  end

  factory :location_2 do
    name 'location_2'
  end

end
```

My unique_locations method works fine in my different environment. I just can't figure out why it's not returning the list of unique locations in test.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Francis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much poking around with Factory_Girl I found the solution:

Here are my factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :provider do
    name 'McGill University'
    description 'McGill is one of the best universities in the world.'
    after(:create) {|provider| create_list(:course, 2, provider: provider) }
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :course do
    name 'Snowboard 101'
    description 'Snowboard course'
    provider
    after(:create) {|course| create_list(:session, 2, course: course) }
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :session do
    name 'Winter Session'
    description 'Snowboarding 101'
    price 150
    class_size 4
    course
    location
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :location do |l|
    l.sequence(:name) { |n| "location_#{n}"}
  end
end
```

I've also updated my test:

```
  test 'should return a list of unique locations' do
    provider = create(:provider)
    assert_equal provider.unique_locations, %w[location_1 location_2 location_3 location_4]
  end
```

This successfully creates 4 different locations.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `FactoryGirl.build(:provider)` which only builds and doesn't save to the DB, so the unique_locations obviously wouldn't have the id to go by. Use `create` and it should fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm using .create but still getting the same error message.